# Add value to self during loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cursor IS SELECT SHIP_ID, DATE_ARRIVE, QTY_EXPECTED, DESCRIPTION, QTY_HAND, ITEM_RATE, (QTY_EXPECTED * ITEM_RATE), ((QTY_EXPECTED * ITEM_RATE) + (QTY_HAND * ITEM_RATE)),((QTY_EXPECTED * ITEM_RATE) + (QTY_HAND * ITEM_RATE))
    FROM SHIPPINGTABLE;
    S_SHIPID SHIPPINGTABLE.SHIP_ID%TYPE;
    S_DATEARRIVE SHIPPINGTABLE.DATE_ARRIVE%TYPE;
    S_QTYEXPECTED SHIPPINGTABLE.QTY_EXPECTED%TYPE;
    S_DESCRIPTION SHIPPINGTABLE.DESCRIPTION%TYPE;
    S_QTYHAND SHIPPINGTABLE.QTY_HAND%TYPE;
    S_ITEMRATE SHIPPINGTABLE.ITEM_RATE%TYPE;
    S_SHIPMENTVALUE NUMBER(10);
    S_TOTALVALUE NUMBER(10);
    S_GRANDTOTAL NUMBER(10) := 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor;
        LOOP
        FETCH CURSOR INTO S_SHIPID, S_DATEARRIVE, S_QTYEXPECTED, S_DESCRIPTION, S_QTYHAND, S_ITEMRATE, S_SHIPMENTVALUE, S_TOTALVALUE, S_GRANDTOTAL;
        EXIT WHEN cursor%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Shipment ' || S_SHIPID || ' is expected to arrive on '|| S_DATEARRIVE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Description: ' || S_DESCRIPTION);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Shipment value: ' || S_SHIPMENTVALUE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Quantity on hand: ' || S_QTYHAND);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total product value: ' || S_TOTALVALUE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));
        S_GRANDTOTAL := S_TOTALVALUE + S_GRANDTOTAL;
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(S_GRANDTOTAL);
        CLOSE cursor;
END;
/
```

I'm trying to calculate the grand total. Right now the output is as follows

```
Shipment 211 is expected to arrive on 15-Nov-07
Description: Season Tents
Shipment value: 12500.
Quantity on hand: 3
Total product value: 14000
```

for each item so that's correct. It also outputs S_GRANDTOTAL, but it only adds the last item to itself so it's not adding the previous item's totals. I know in java you can do something like

`variable += variable`

Is there a way to do this in sql as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PL/SQL equivalent to Java's [variable1 += variable2] is [variable1 := variable1 + variable2]. So at first glance, your [S_GRANDTOTAL := S_TOTALVALUE + S_GRANDTOTAL] looks correct. However, in your SQL statement, the source derivation of GRANDTOTAL is identical to that of TOTAL_VALUE [((QTY_EXPECTED * ITEM_RATE) + (QTY_HAND * ITEM_RATE))]. Remove the last field definition from the SQL statement, and the [[INTO] S_GRANDTOTAL] element from the cursor fetch statement, and I think your code will work as you intend; the TOTAL_VALUE will be added to the S_GRAND_TOTAL variable cummulatively from zero to final and be displayed at the end of the report.

It would be helpful if you would alias the derived fields in the SQL statement, i.e.: SELECT SHIP_ID, DATE_ARRIVE, QTY_EXPECTED, DESCRIPTION, QTY_HAND, ITEM_RATE, (QTY_EXPECTED * ITEM_RATE) **AS SHIPMENT_VALUE**, ((QTY_EXPECTED * ITEM_RATE) + (QTY_HAND * ITEM_RATE)) **AS TOTAL_VALUE**

A PL/SQL cursor loop like this is not scalable, that is, it will bring your system to its knees if the tables contain millions or billions of rows and/or there is high activity besides this on your system.
For this reason I would recommend using a reporting tool on the front end and a single SQL (not PL/SQL cursor loop) statement on the back end.  Let the tool do the multi-level detail, aggregations and roll-ups.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I understand that it might not be scalable, but I don't have to worry about that since it's just for a homework assignment.

Comment: When you get out of school and into the profession (out of boot camp and onto a battlefield), you will perform as you have trained. Always try to think beyond the immediate problem to how this would really work in a production environment with all the elements, conditions, resources and constraints (technical, organizational, bureaucratic) that will be present there.

Comment: I understand, I just don't have any exposure to other tools and I don't plan on using SQL in my career.